# MS Access queries to MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access

I got a problem on MS Access queries to MySQL table

I'm new to both database.

I got a query on MS Access and now I have to migrate to MySQL.

The question is I need to create a table or a view to let the program get data from.

```
CREATE TABLE Subsequence AS
SELECT 'A' AS Type,br, comm, identifier, app_type, Min(timestamp) AS timestampOfMin
FROM trans_log
WHERE (((trans_log.table_type)='APPARATUS') AND ((trans_log.action)='APPROVAL'))
GROUP BY br, comm, identifier, app_type
UNION SELECT 'C' AS Type,br, comm, identifier, app_type, Min(timestamp) AS timestampOfMin
FROM (select * from trans_log where action='CEASE_APPARATUS') AS B
GROUP BY br, comm, identifier, app_type
ORDER BY timestampOfMin;
```

It is the code for the table.

The question are,

1)while my trans_log update, Can I get the latest data inside this table?

2)Do I have to set up a foreign key?

3) if no, any method?

I'm new to these database, Thank you for your help.

Comment: Export MSAccess data to csv then import to mysql.

Comment: thank you. It helps